# Can't update alpha channel on Google Play Store for security issue, but no security issues are listed

Tags: android, security, alpha, google-play-console, prelaunch

I currently have a production release of an application for the company I work for on the Play Store, we recently updated our code and tried to release the update via a beta channel and noticed we were losing a bunch of devices due to usb.host features not being compatible with devices. We moved over to an alpha channel for fixes and testing.

After fixing the manifest to ignore that issue (since we didn't require the feature for application to run) I ran into an issue where we were getting AWS security issues.

That was also fixed; I thought that was done, but now for some reason it still indicates that we have security issues, even though no info is given on what security issues there are in the pre-launch report.

[image]
[image]

It seems emails take forever to be received from the google play console because (took about 14 days for them to reply to me) and it's irritating me how little information they give.

If I go to the main page where it shows "All of my applications" and hover over the warning symbol it says my updates were rejected for the AWS credential issue but it says it only effects older versions.

[image]

I DO have other warnings in the pre-launch reports (once again, if i click on security warning, it says their are none, like shown in picture above), but I did not think these warnings would prevent my app from being released to alpha, and it does not say this either. It currently shows I have Accessibility and Compatibility warnings.

[image]

I have setup my alpha channels correctly as well (according to documentation). I have a list of testers, checked and saved in the closed alpha test track and have sent them the link to opt-in to the channel (I myself have as well), which they have accepted. I have made sure to use the app on the play store and can see that I am in the beta. I have tried clearing the google play cache as well since that seems to be a solution I have been seeing but still no update is available.

Once again, i'm not receiving emails back about why it was rejected or from my inquiries....and the one I have received a reply was 14 days later (earlier inquiry i have resolved).

Any help would be appreciated. We are holding up a release because of this.

***UPDATE***

Found out backing out to main page that shows ALL of our applications and looking at Alert menu showed that we had another security issue. I have also fixed that but it still seems like it is not posting the update. Now the only info I see that it is rejected is this:

[image]

I still also see the same warnings mentioned earlier in the pre-launch report. But nothing indicating that it would prevent the app from not being posted.

Comment: It says what your problem is.  Your app has exposed AWS credentials.  The solution is not to ship your app with AWS credentials in your apk-  that's extremely insecure.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I already mentioned above that it states that issue is for earlier versions. The pre-launch report shows no issues in security for the current release.

Comment: From the screenshot you showed, it doesn't look like you've fixed it.  Or at least it doesn't think you have

Comment: 34207 shows nothing is wrong with security when clicking on more info in the pre-launch report. 

Main screen says their are AWS Credential issues for EARLIER VERSIONS (34205, 342, etc)

After i fixed AWS credential issue in later release, the same warning i was getting before is gone.

Comment: You need to make sure all issues are fixed in all tracks (including alpha and beta tracks. Do you possibly still have an old version active with issues in a testing track?

Comment: Yup @NickFortescue ,  that ended up being the issue. I was finally able to speak to someone and they said ALL tracks must be fixed before I could use the test track. Our production track had an issue that needed to be fixed by the first of the year and it had not been fixed (i'm the new guy so I didn't know about that issue) so this was the only way to fix it.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, I fixed the issues and published it in beta channel but Play store rejecting beta channel due to issue not fixed in production. Now only way seems to release to production hoping everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

@NickFortescue that ended up being the issue. I was finally able to speak to someone and they said ALL tracks must be fixed before I could use the test track. Our production track had an issue that needed to be fixed by the first of the year and it had not been fixed (i'm the new guy so I didn't know about that issue) so this was the only way to fix it.